How to identify user satisfaction after personalizing a website's content?
Personalizing content on a website allows you to adapt the experience based on user preferences, behaviors, and needs, providing a more efficient and relevant navigation. However, after implementing improvements to content and layout, how can you identify whether these changes have actually resulted in an increase in user satisfaction? What metrics or signals can be used to measure the effectiveness of these personalizations and assess the impact on the user experience?
We often see traditional metrics, such as time spent on the site, bounce rate, and clicks, used to assess the impact of personalization. However, when these metrics do not show significant variations, it can be challenging to determine whether the changes have actually improved the user experience. This is precisely my "problem" and doubt when making a change to the content of the website (especially when it involves a major change), because factors such as the navigation context, the type of content consumed, and even the nature of the interaction can directly influence the user's perception, complicating the analysis of the results. Additionally, user satisfaction may depend on more subjective variables, such as perceived relevance of content and ease of use, which are not always captured by quantitative metrics.
I would like to understand how to measure the success of these initiatives and understand how users respond after the changes are implemented.
